Filter a tree with polymorphic nodes in Typescript
Consider this generic tree structure:
export interface TreeItem {
    subItems?: TreeItem[];
}

The nodes are polymorphic. In effect, this is what I put in the tree :
export type MenuItem = TreeItem & {
    someText: string;
};

export class MenuItemTypeA implements MenuItem {
    public someFieldExclusiveToTypeA: string;
    public subItems: MenuItem[];
}

export class MenuItemTypeB implements MenuItem {
    public someFieldExclusiveToTypeB: string;
    public subItems: MenuItem[];
}

Example of tree
const tree = [
   new MenuItemTypeA("a1", [
       new MenuItemTypeB("b2", []),
       new MenuItemTypeA("a2", [])
   ]),
   new MenuItemTypeB("b1", [])
]

Now this the generic method that lets me filter the tree, by passing a predicate method (filter) which decides if the node stays in the tree or not :
public static filterTree<T extends TreeItem>(nodes: T[], filter: (node: T) => boolean): T[] {
    const updatedItems = [];
    for (const node of nodes) {
        if (filter(node)) {
            updatedItems.push(node);
        }
        node.subItems = this.filterTree(node.subItems ?? [], filter);
    }
    return updatedItems;
}

For example :
const filteredTree = filterTree(tree, (_) => true); // Leaves all the nodes

Problem :
Typescript is not happy with this line :
node.subItems = this.filterTree(node.subItems ?? [], filter);

Error:
Argument of type TreeItem[] is not assignable to parameter of type T[]
Type TreeItem is not assignable to type T
TreeItem is assignable to the constraint of type T, but T could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint TreeItem

I'm not sure what the problem is, as I'm not re-instantiating anything, just copying the nodes' references without changing the nodes themselves.
Is there an easy fix? More genrally, is this approach flawed? (i.e. what is a good practice for a generic tree with strongly-typed polymorphic nodes? I couldn't figure it out with only interfaces)

T extends TreeItem seems way too generic. I can write interface MyTreeItem extends TreeItem { subItems: undefined } without error, but if you ran filter on that, you'd be sad (trying to assign [] to undefined). It might be possible to convince TS to allow what you're doing, but I'd think the way to do this is to make TreeItem itself generic, and then have filter be generic in the type parameter for TreeItem, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
